# huge amount of TCP connections on 1GE port

Tags: centos, vmware-esxi, hardware

I have a Rackmount server with ESXI 4 and on top I have 12 VMs with Centos 5.X.
I have 2 CPUs with 6 core each (total of 12) and 40GB of RAM.

all VMs are connected on one 1GE port.

I need to know if the server (hardware / software (ESXI) can hold up to 30,000 TCP connections?

Thanks!!
Dotan.

Comment: There's only way to find out and that's to test it.

Comment: can you recommend a tool?

Comment: I can, but shouldn't http://compnetworking.about.com/od/networkperformance/TCPIP_Network_Performance_Benchmarks_and_Tools.htm

Comment: Google is not that hard :)

Comment: I've done just under 50,000 TCP connections on a Pentium 166 with a fast Ethernet port and 96MB of RAM using Linux 2.4 as the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it depends on the amount of traffic per connection but 50k connections across 12 VMs is only 4,166 per VM which they can easily manage and your 1Gbps NIC can handle ~666,666 1,500-byte packets per second either way, so even if every one of your connections required 13 of those packets per second then the server should be able to keep up.

Whether your network and/or application could maintain that I don't know but the server should be able to keep up just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For ESX, it has no tools to perform network speed testing.

It's recommend to use a VM and use any testing tools to test it.